# Error signing assembly due to AVG anti virus

Tags: visual-studio-2010, antivirus, assembly-signing

The IT department updated the AVG antivirus software on my development machine yesterday and now I get the following error when I try to compile my assembly:

*error CS1606: Assembly signing failed; output may not be signed -- Error signing assembly -- The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.*

The assembly is written C# using VS2010. I am signing the assembly using a strong name key file.

When I run in safe mode, or temporarily disable AVG protection there are no errors.

I've closed VS and built using MSBuild on the command line.
I've ran "sn -c" to reset the CSP to the default.
I've tried adding various Exceptions to the AVG:

- C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\
- My source code directory
- Even went to the extreme and added "C:\"

None of that worked.

Of course, I could always just have the virus protection disabled, but I don't think the IT department would be too happy about it.

Any thoughts?